# Tracking visitors' choices with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web-applications, tracking

I have been asked to make it possible to track visitors' choices in a 10-step product mockup generator in order to find out which options are most popular.

All we really need is to be able to compare the popularity of different choices side-by-side. Also, it would be very neat if it were possible to track only the latest choices of any unique visitor.

I imagine this is achievable with GA at least to some extent. If so, where do I begin?

I'm not very familiar with GA yet, so please excuse me if what I'm asking is GA basics. As a non-native English speaker and a total GA newbie I couldn't come up with specific enough search terms for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this detailed guide on [Event Tracking in GA](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

If I were to do this, I would have the event category as the product step, the event label as the choice, the event action as the type of choice (checkbox, button, etc) and I would use the event value parameter for the input values (this is an optional parameter, but it can be pretty useful)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the answer might've been in events but dismissed it for now in favor of other work and because I didn't think events were the right way to express this kind of data. I'll take a closer look and come back later to accept your answer if events are indeed the thing I'm looking for(or there's no better alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Setup GA event tracking with a goal funnel, this will help visualize the process (Start to end). Also you could track events on each item to get a total "hit" value. Keep the Category and naming consistent for easy reporting.

Comment: will that also track the same user across visits or will it only record the current session? I would like to know for example if someone visits my site 2 weeks later etc